# The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid. Node http-proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I believe I am missing a fundimental part of the proxy set up here but when using the following:

```
var http = require('http'),
    httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
      httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'http://www.asos.com'}).listen(8000); 

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.write('request successfully proxied!' + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
    res.end();
}).listen(9000);
```

To be presented by:

```
Invalid URL

The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid.
Reference #9.56731002.1508760714.1524ffde
```

now I am pretty sure this is a url entered into the proxy?

All I want to do is setup up a proxy to a site and then insert some custom js file. But this is step one.

Comment: Exactly when and where are you seeing this error message?

Comment: Indeed, I am a fool. I was accessing localhost:8000... now accessing 9000 it works. If u wanna add the answer for some other fools then I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd also be happy to delete the question, just depends if others might benefit from this? I personally believe they would as that would have saved me a few (15) mins of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to what you've said in the comments you were correct to try to access `localhost:8000`. That is the correct port for the proxy you created.

You need to add this:

```
changeOrigin: true
```

In full:

```
httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    changeOrigin: true,
    target: 'http://www.asos.com'
}).listen(8000);
```

Without that setting the remote server will be receiving a request with the header `Host: localhost:8000` and it seems that this particular server cares about the `Host` header (perhaps it's using virtual hosts). As a result it won't know what to do with it and it's returning that error. The proxy is successfully proxying the error message from the remote server.

You've clearly copied your code from the `http-proxy` documentation but you seem to have misunderstood it. Notice that in the original example the proxy `target` is `localhost:9000`, which is the same server it subsequently creates. So the intention of that example is that you will access `localhost:8000` and it will proxy the request to `localhost:9000`. What you've trying to do is quite different. Your code is creating two completely independent servers, one on port 8000 and one on port 9000.

Rather than using the `listen` method you might be better off looking at the examples for the `web` method.

Comment: Indeed, great help.  I missed this whole thing and skipped to getting it done. Thank you for pointing that out:
web req, res, [options] (used for proxying regular HTTP(S) requests)
ws req, socket, head, [options] (used for proxying WS(S) requests)
listen port (a function that wraps the object in a webserver, for your convenience)
close [callback] (a function that closes the inner webserver and stops listening on given port)

Comment: Now I will need to work out if I need a server running, I will need some logic to add some files to the page before loading, so I imagine one `listen` with one `web`

Comment: It would seem, doing a proxy over `asos.com` is actually very difficult as it has around 4 reidrects :O